# Is there an dynamically changing font?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-recommendation, resource-recommendations

Just had this idea, and thought to post it here to get an answer as to its existence. I'm thinking something that isn't perfectly monospaced/spaced, but as you type it organically lays out the font with random splines or something and random spacing, but the splines would be contained inside a shape of a letter that would also be randomly scaled and rotated just slightly across each character stroke.

Comment: Probably not, but this could be achieved via scripting.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your mean but you can create some pseudo-randomness with OpenType features that can probably do what you want.